# Create a line chart from two non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, charts, line, pywin32

I have to create a line chart from the first and third column of a three-column sheet.

For example

```
Gender Responses  Index
Female   325      2.52
Male     243      3.15
Other    127      4.21
```

that is, values should be taken from Index whereas labels from Gender. So I wrote

```
chart = excel.Charts.Add(After=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
chart.Name = "LineChart"
chart.Type = win32c.xlLine
chart.HasTitle = True
chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Just a title"
chart.SetSourceData(dist_ws.Range("A1:A4", "C1:C4"))
```

but it does not work. The range gets all the three columns and in any case I get an Exception. I also tried

```
chart.SetSourceData(dist_ws.Range("A1:A4, C1:C4"))
```

and

```
chart.SetSourceData(dist_ws.Range("A2:A4, C1:C4"))
```

but it does not work. So I need to separately set source data (in C2:C4 with Series name in C1) and X axis labels (in A2:A4).

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A guess, but try `dist_ws.Range("A1:A4,C1:C4"))`

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: No. It does not work. I have to find to set separately the values and the category labels of X Axis for a line chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a completely different way:

```
# FIRST, I create a new sheet to allocate chart
chart_ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
chart_ws.Name = "Anyname"

# SECOND, I add a line chart in it
chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, win32c.xlLineMarkers, 0, 0, 560, 320).Select()
chart = wb.ActiveChart
chart.HasTitle = True
chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Any title"

# THIRD, I create a series for data
series = chart.SeriesCollection().NewSeries()

# FOURTH, I set the two ranges for labels and values
# Warning: ranges do NOT includes headers (A1 and C1)
# A1 is used to name the series
series.XValues = dist_ws.Range("A2:A4")
series.Values = dist_ws.Range("C2:C4")
series.Name = dist_ws.Range("A1").Value
```

It works.